# How to use some Vue components in server-side-rendered page

Tags: vue.js, components, single-page-application, vuejs3, server-side-rendering

I would like to slowly transform parts of my existing server-side-rendered website into vue components. The way it is done on this livestream (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qVueTeO4yMs&t=960s).

So, there is one wrapping `<div id="app">` that surrounds all the normal ssr html. On some pages, there are `<custom-element>` vue components, that should be rendered in place.

This is what I have atm:

```html
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <h1>SSR content</h1>
        This should stay
        <testing-component></testing-component> <-- render the component here
    </div>
</body>
```

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import TestingComponent from './components/TestingComponent.vue';


const app = createApp({
    el: '#app'
});

app.component('testing-component', TestingComponent);
```

But this isn't rendering anything.

Adding `app.mount("#app");` overwrites everything within my `<div id="app">`.

So, how to mount the component, without replacing everything in my `<div id="app">`?

**UPDATE**

Forgot to mention I was using Vite. And with updating some settings in the vite config file I could make it work:

vite.config.js

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js', // This was needed.
    },
  },
})
```

Entrypoint vue:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import TestingComponent from './components/TestingComponent.vue';


const app = createApp({
}).mount("#app");

app.component('testing-component', TestingComponent);
```

This will increase the build file, so I was told.

Comment: You could add a template for home where all your stuff is nested in, so that div app is effectively empty and you work from the templates downward. 
Otherwise you could mount the component for itself in a div if you don't have to rely on cross-component communication for now. `<div id="myComponent"></div>` | `const app.mount('#myComponent')`